# Android: Animation of slide up to below of another view.

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview

Is there any idea or how can i achieve this Animation like following picture? because i tried to give a animation on Linearlayout B when i pressed a cancel button, the linearlayout B will slide out from left to right but once LinearLayout B fully Gone, the LinearLayout C directly step to below of LinearLayout A rather than slide slowly to below of LinearLayout A. please help...

[image: Slide Animation]

Comment: do you want only collapse animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the linear layout and you will achieve this automatically.

Comment: Which LinearLayout u mention? B or C?

Comment: The one that holds all the linear layouts.

Comment: ya this work, thanks.. is that work for Listview item swipe out also?

Comment: just so you are aware, animateLayoutChanges wasn't available before Honeycomb

Comment: because the thing i am going to on is listview header, i tried that work fine for LinearLayout C to slide up slowly, but actually this whole view is Listview and LinearLayout A,B,C is inside a header View of listview and i got the problem is the item of listview step to the position directly before LinearLayout C slide up. i thought it will follow up LinearLayout C to slide slowly as well. do u have solution for this problem? how ever that is my fault because i didn't mention that is lsitview, thanks any way!

Comment: you are saying that those linear layouts are inside a `ListView`? this works for listviews also. I am not sure I understand exactly what you have there.

Comment: ya, because it is not good for having listview inside scollview therefore i created another layout to group linearlayout A,B,C and inflate it as a View and use listview.addheaderview to add the inflated view. i tried add android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to listview but it not work. if i add on the group that containing all those linearlayout, it work find, but the item of listview will step before the linearlayot C slide up.

Answer (score 0):

First add a ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDraw listener to the view C:

```
int bHeight = viewB.getHeight();
viewC.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        viewC.startAnimation(new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, bHeight, 0));
        viewC.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then set the visibility of B to gone.

```
viewB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

What this does is hides the view B, causing the view C to move up. However before C is drawn in it's new position we animate it from where it used to be to where it is now.

Comment: i tried, it seem like not work for me, the return type should set false right? is that work for listview? because the thing i am going to do is on listview header. base on the question i ask, bogdan answer is work fine. But for listview item it still step on directly before linearlayout C sliding up.